# How to get model's relation by name?

Tags: php, laravel

Is there a way to call a relation by it's name?

instead of this:

```
$user->comments()->create([]);
```

I want to use something like this:

```
$relation = 'comments';
$user->getRelation($relation)->create([]);
```

I have tried this, but I am getting :

```
"Undefined index: comments"
```

Comment: `$user->$relation()->create()` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two scenarios you need to consider.

1) When you created a user and comments are not attached to it `getRelation($string)` returns `Error: undefine index RELATION NAME`
2) When you have user with comments and finding relation through `getRelation($string)` works like a  charm.

Workaround for the problem is you need to load the relation first. Let me give you an example.

```
$user = new User();
$relation = 'comments';
//load method is used to load a relation.
$user->load($relation)->create(['field_name'=>"SOME VALUE"]);
```

Try it out and let me know whether it worked or not.

Comment: Glat it helped. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you must to be more specific. But if you wanna get the results of a relationship with eloquent you can do:

```
$books = App\Book::with('author')->get();
```

Where author, is a relationship.

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to provide a dynamic relation name? If so you can do it like this:

```
$relation = 'comments';

$user->$relation->create([]);
```